# Querying Data from SQL Database based on Date in Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I needed help learning how to query data from a SQL database based on the date, and then populate that data into a TextView. I have five columns; each column is supposed to populate in a separate TextView.

Let's say that one TextView looks like this:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/PrayerTitle"
        android:text="@string/PrayerTimesTitle"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display2" />
```

How would I put data from my SQL database based on today's date into this TextView?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your question is not clear are you asking about fetching the data or setting a value to a TextView

Comment: I mean setting a value to a TextView from the SQL database.

Comment: Are you newbie to Android app development ?  Is your question how data can be queried from a sqlite database and displayed on a textview ?

Comment: Yes and yes. I'm a newbie, and that is my question. Couldn't find enough info on developer.android.com, so I thought I could ask here.

Comment: ok my friend I have a lot of question before answering you: did add the sql database to your asset folder? which fetcher are you using (example https://gist.github.com/mikeplate/9173040 or https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Local-Databases-with-SQLiteOpenHelper) do you know how to set a text to the `TextView`? or are you using another database like Realm.io?

Comment: I hope this isn't too much work for you, @zombie, but could you walk me through setting the TextView using Java and access the DB using all of the methods you mentioned before? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which folder should I put the DB in? I'm using Android Studio.